# Define own date intervals with startDate and endDate in a new variable

Tags: java, jasper-reports, expression, bar-chart

I am struggling with a date calculation to define my own range for a bar chart series.

My dynamic dates are parameters the timestamp parameters "timestamp1", "timestamp2", "timestamp3", "timestamp4" wheras I want to create the intervals

interval1: days between "timestamp1" and "timestamp2"

interval2: days between "timestamp3" and "timestamp4".

What is the expression that I have to add to my variables in order to have two time intervals for my bar chart series? I am completely lost with this issue.

Comment: How are the dates currently represented in your program?  Also, do you care about time of day as well, or just the date without the time?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances to me.  The best answer to that question is Michal's answer, near the bottom, because it takes account of daylight savings time correctly.

Comment: I am going to downvote any answer that doesn't deal with daylight savings correctly, by the way.  Just subtracting the milliseconds and dividing by 86400000 would fit into that category.

Comment: In which format your timestamp? I mean you should have date in string like "dd-mm-yyyy" or as well?

Comment: This is a related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37579395/5292302)

Answer (score 1):

As commented by David Wallace, you should look at the question [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555262/642706). And search for other questions with "joda" and "interval".

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)  2.3 is an open-source library for handling date-time calculations. Joda-Time has inspired the creation of the java.time.* classes being built into Java 8.

As [discussed in the doc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_interval.html), Joda-Time offers the [Interval class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) for exactly your needs: Handling a pair of start-stop dates in an intelligent manner, savvy with time zones and [Daylight Savings Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and other anomalies.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );  // Current moment in Paris.
Interval interval = new Interval( now, now.plusHours( 8 ) );
```

To describe the time span (elapsed), see the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) and [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) classes. They can describe the years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds in human language (French, English, etc.). They can describe the span in ISO 8601 format of [PnYnMnDTnHnMnS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

---

Further tips…

For representing a single moment in time, use the [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.

When necessary to interact with other classes that know only java.util.Date, call the `toDate` method.

Note that you should avoid using the java.util.Date/Calendar classes, as they are badly designed and implemented. Java 8 will supplant them with the java.time.* classes mentioned above.

Comment: The question was about *JasperReports*

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a complete different approach. So if anyone may want to add time intervals into an iReprt chart, consider the following:

I summed up the download numbers from each time interval in my SQL query. Like that:

```
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN Downloads.ExtractDate BETWEEN "$P{myTimestamp1}" AND "$P{myTimestamp2}" THEN Downloads.Downloads ELSE 0 END) AS Sum1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Downloads.ExtractDate BETWEEN "$P{myTimestamp2}" AND "$P{myTimestamp3}" THEN Downloads.Downloads ELSE 0 END) As Sum
FROM aacdb.Downloads
```

In iReport, I created a bar chart using the following Chart Series Information (*right click on chart* -> *Chart Data* -> *Details*):

**SERIES 1**

Series Expression

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format($P{myTimestamp1})) + " - " + (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format($P{myTimestamp2}))
```

Category Expression

```
$F{Name}
```

Value Expression

```
$F{Sum1}
```

**SERIES 2**

Series Expression

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format($P{myTimestamp2})) + " - " + (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format($P{myTimestamp3}))
```

Category Expression

```
$F{Name}
```

Value Expression

```
$F{Sum2}
```

Thanks to everyone for the effort